# Matlab cannot find the C/C++ compiler although I have it installed

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm trying to run `mex -setup` in matlab, but it gives me the following error

```
>> mex -setup
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit...
```

I looked into the compilers that are supported with my version of matlab(2015a) and it is stated [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2015a_SupportedCompilers.pdf?sec=win64) that the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 professional" is supported. I looked into my programs and found "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable".

My question is that are those the same? If they are the same why my Matlab cannot find the compiler?

Comment: The redistributable is just needed DLL components if you don't compile to a standalone program. You will need to install the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use lcc-win with Matlab. And it should come with Matlab (if not you can get it from Jacob Navia https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/). Whilst you have MS Visual Studio installed, Matlab isn't finding it - maybe the redistributable isn't the same version as Matlab needs or you need to tell it the path. But lcc-win is the route most Matlab users go and there is less to go wrong.

Comment: It doesn't support c++ for my version of matlab